# Adding custom meta into wordpress search

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to add my theme posts custom meta values into search query, but it's not working for me. For example **_My_meta_value_key3** is product code, but if i try to search it, wp don't find the match. I really want to make this without any plugins so any suggestions are welcome. Also, this code is currently located in theme functions.

```
function My_custom_search_query( $query ) {
if ($query->is_search()) {
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        array(
        'key' => '_My_meta_value_key',
        'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
        'key' => '_My_meta_value_key2',
        'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
        'key' => '_My_meta_value_key3',
        'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ));
    return $query;
};}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'My_custom_search_query');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent an hour searching for a solution and there was nothing that works so I had to write the solution on my own. It is **tested and working with Wordpress 5.3.1** and is the only solution that solves this problem I could find on the internet.

Place the following code in your functions.php file to hook into `posts_clauses` filter.

```
/**
 * Include meta fields in search
 * 
 * @author Mindaugas // meevly.com
 * @link https://meevly.com/services/custom-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/
 * 
 * @param array $pieces query pieces.
 * @param WP_Query $args query object.
 * @return array
 */
function mv_meta_in_search_query( $pieces, $args ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! empty( $args->query['s'] ) ) { // only run on search query.
        $keywords        = explode(' ', get_query_var('s'));
        $escaped_percent = $wpdb->placeholder_escape(); // WordPress escapes "%" since 4.8.3 so we can't use percent character directly.
        $query           = "";

        foreach ($keywords as $word) {
            $query .= " (unique_postmeta_selector.meta_value LIKE '{$escaped_percent}{$word}{$escaped_percent}') OR ";
        }

        if ( ! empty( $query ) ) { // append necessary WHERE and JOIN options.
            $pieces['where'] = str_replace( "((({$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '{$escaped_percent}", "( {$query} (({$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '{$escaped_percent}", $pieces['where'] );
            $pieces['join'] = $pieces['join'] . " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS unique_postmeta_selector ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = unique_postmeta_selector.post_id) ";
        }
    }

    return $pieces;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'mv_meta_in_search_query', 20, 2 );
```

And your query should look like the following. **Please note that `suppress_filters => false` is mandatory**! It will not work without it.

```
$search_posts_array = array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    's'                => $keyword,
);

$search_results = get_posts( $search_posts_array );
```

Please do not hesitate to credit if I saved you tons of time! :)

Comment: got multiple results of the same object for some searchs values.. but exept that it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Found this http://wpdevsnippets.com/extend-search-include-custom-fields-without-plugin/ :

```
function custom_search_where($pieces) {

// filter to select search query
if (is_search() && !is_admin()) {

    global $wpdb;
    $custom_fields = array('field1','field2'); // Array for custom meta fields
    $keywords = explode(' ', get_query_var('s'));
    $query = "";
    foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
         foreach ($keywords as $word) {
             $query .= "((mypm1.meta_key = '".$field."')";
             $query .= " AND (mypm1.meta_value  LIKE '%{$word}%')) OR ";
         }
    }

    if (!empty($query)) {
        // add to where clause
        $pieces['where'] = str_replace("(((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%", "( {$query} ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%", $pieces['where']);

        $pieces['join'] = $pieces['join'] . " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS mypm1 ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = mypm1.post_id)";
    }
}
return ($pieces);
}

add_filter('posts_clauses', 'custom_search_where', 20, 1);
```